# Why does HTML5 video with very large h.264 encoded mp4 (with +faststart, ie metadata at beginning), take ages to load?

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video

The video is rendered with ffmpeg with the "faststart" flag added meaning the metadata should be at the start of the file, and the server appears to be handling partial content requests correctly, so why does it need to have downloaded so much of the video before the player becomes enabled and can play the video? I am testing it in Google Chrome.

Once the player becomes enabled I can seek around to various points in the video pretty instantly and see the new partial content requests being made.

Here is a link to the video: <s>http://iptv.la1tv.co.uk/unibrass.mp4</s>

Here is a jsbin with the video tag: https://jsbin.com/rahewidoru . It takes a few minutes but does work after it loads.

Any suggestions?

I realise there are other methods like HLS and dash which use chunks, but I would like to know why it isn't working this way because I can't find anywhere that provides a reason as to why it doesn't work well.

Comment: how optimized is the video for the target playback size? It will need to buffer enough content to for the canPlayThru flag to fire so if it's very high resolution you won't get an instant start. for me it starts playing (not cached) in <6s

Comment: Thanks that's interesting. That's a 720p render with a bitrate of 2.5mb/s. Do you know of any mp4 encodes for web that are several hours long that I could use to compare with that one?

(https://github.com/LA1TV/Website-Upload-Processor/blob/177df3797b9ba9cbeee758102d181041051e4a9a/src/main/java/uk/co/la1tv/websiteUploadProcessor/fileTypes/VODVideoFileType.java#L137)

Comment: For me it is having to download to around 44mb before the "loadeddata", "loadedmetadata", and "canplay" events fire and the player is enabled. Is this around the same number for you?

Comment: watching network tools in Chrome/OSX I also see about 44mb downloaded after hitting play before the video starts rolling. adding `preload="auto"` might help. what browser/os? Speedtest says Comcast are delivering about 108Mbps today for me. my usual encode is something like `ffmpeg -y -i SourceFile.mp4 -s 1280x720 -c:v libx264 -b 3M -strict -2 -movflags faststart DestFile.mp4` and seems to be okay for speed/quality

Comment: Yes so it looks like it thinks it only has all the metadata it needs after that point, but I can't believe that there is 44mb of metadata! I'm on windows and the same delay is occurring in microsoft edge and chrome, not tested other browsers but presuming it will be the same. Thanks for that. I'm going to re-encode the entire file with handbrake optimised for web and see if that works meaning there's something funny with the encode. If that fixes it I'll then start comparing my ffmpeg command with yours.

Comment: I don't think it's 44mb of metadata, but probably that plus enough to fill the buffer for it to be confident it can play the whole video (as it's pretty long it might want that). There is a javascript MPEG-DASH library if you want to go cross-browser chunked solution...

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try this first then might have to move to a chunked solution. I checked the events though and the canplaythrough and loadedmetadata events fired at the same time.

Comment: "I can't believe that there is 44mb of metadata!" Believe it. I looked at the file with a hex editor. The moov atom is 46073814 bytes.

Comment: Is this normal then for a 9 hour file or is it an encoding issue? If it's normal then I guess switching to a chunked solution is the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like it is just how h.264 works. The metadata contains pointers to all the keyframes in the file, and therefore as the duration of the file increases, so does the number of keyframes, and hence the size of metadata at the beginning.

More information at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html

If anyone can provide a more in depth answer as to what the metadata in a h.264 encoded mp4 contains then let me know and I'll mark that as the answer, or just edit this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the duration of the video, I don't know the exact duration of the video, but I can estimate based in the video size.

The reason is the video player implementation reads some pieces around the video to take some information information for the playback and forward and to ensure that the header is well formed.

For this reason is very important make use of streaming protocols such HLS o DASH because the situation of time stamps is different and it is optimized for streaming.