# Create a video-streaming server from a raw H.264 frame stream

Tags: c#, c, video-streaming, h.264

I have a IP camera (VisionTech VN6xSM3Ti) which returns me a video stream of H.264 raw data, how can I use this stream to create a live-stream that can be accessed through an HTML5 browser?

To access the camera stream, I must follow a specified protocol from the manufacturer, so it's not as easy as to just access it with the IP address.

I already have the code in C# and C that reads the camera stream as a byte array, but I don't know how to go on.

I've been thinking on solving it with Node.JS and my code as follows:

1. Access the camera stream with my code and expose it through a local socket
2. In Node.JS access the created socket and stream its contents to all the clients

IP Camera raw Data ---> My Code --- Local Socket --> Node.js --- ?? ---> Clients

Does anyone knows if this can be done? or is if there's a better option?

Answer (score 1):

**Assumptions:**
I am assuming the following: the H264 stream is AnnexB type, you can read it in chunks and the prerequisite is to write the data in chunks (streaming). The output data is playable in a browser without any extensions or special players.

**Proposal:**
You need to read a chunk of data, remux the raw h264 data to fragmented mp4 and send the chunk of that file to a client. In order to do that, probably the easiest solution would be to use [FFMpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) and pipes.

*FFMpeg:*
FFMpeg can use pipe input and output ([answer ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899585/pipe-input-in-to-ffmpeg)). To receive the raw h264 stream, remux the stream to a mp4 that is fragmented [(answer ref)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616855/how-to-output-fragmented-mp4-with-ffmpeg) and write an output do the following (not tested):

```
ffmpeg -f h264 -i pipe: -c copy -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov pipe:
```

That command will read raw h264 data from a standard input, copy the stream (no re-encoding) and mux it to a fragmented mp4 to standard output.

In C# you can start an external process [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8), write to its [Process.StandardInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput?view=netcore-2.2) the bytes you receive and read the [Process.StandardOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=netcore-2.2). The output should be [fragmented mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177797/what-exactly-is-fragmented-mp4fmp4-how-is-it-different-from-normal-mp4) which should be playable in a browser.

**Remarks**:
   1. A drawback would be an inability to seek a video, but if I understood you correctly, it is a live stream, so that should be fine.
   2. The input stream is not re-encoded, only remuxed. That is the fastest processing, but if you want more control: e.g. to output h265 or to specify the fragment size then a stream must be re-encoded during the process (high CPU usage).