# How to fragment an mp4 file using ffmpeg.

Tags: ffmpeg, fragment, mp4

How to fragment an mp4 file using ffmpeg.I have followed this command "[How to output fragmented mp4 with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616855/how-to-output-fragmented-mp4-with-ffmpeg)" but it almost doubles the file size. Is there any other way ?

Comment: I have read this stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616855/how-to-output-fragmented-mp4-with-ffmpeg.
but the command mentioned here. doubles the file size. is there any other way?

Comment: This is not related to programming....

Answer (score 1):

I think you get a higher file size because you reencode it with higher bitrates than the input file.

In the linked answer, you can modify the settings for `-ab` and `-vb`:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.ext -g 52 \
-strict experimental -acodec aac -ab 64k -vcodec libx264 -vb 448k \
-f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov \
output.mp4
```

(Hint: Do not user `-re` if not necessary)

If you don't have the bitrates from the input file, use ffprobe to get it for all streams:

```
ffprobe -i input.mp4
```

(look for Stream#0:0, Stream#0:1 and so on and if it is Audio or Video)

**Not tested**:
You can also try to copy the streams:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -g 52 \
-strict experimental -c copy \
-f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov \
output.mp4
```

(only works with mp4 input?!)