# Create fragmented MP4 from MP3

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, mp4, fmp4

I am trying to convert an MP3 file to a fragmented MP4 like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -strict experimental -acodec aac -b:a 256k -f mp4 \
       -movflags faststart+frag_keyframe+empty_moov+separate_moof output.mp4
```

However, using [Bento4](https://github.com/axiomatic-systems/Bento4) I can see that there is just *one* giant `mdat` object instead of a series of those:

```
[ftyp] size=8+24
  major_brand = isom
  minor_version = 200
  compatible_brand = isom
  compatible_brand = iso2
  compatible_brand = iso6
  compatible_brand = mp41
[moov] size=8+701
  ...
[moof] size=8+62364
  ...
[mdat] size=8+5794679
[mfra] size=8+59
  [tfra] size=12+31, version=1
    track_ID = 1
    length_size_of_traf_num = 0
    length_size_of_trun_num = 0
    length_size_of_sample_num = 0
  [mfro] size=12+4
    mfra_size = 67
```

I think what I want is this:

[image]

([source](https://bitmovin.com/fun-with-container-formats-2/))

But I can't seem to be able to get this from `ffmpeg`.

I found some other options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10454207/826983) like

```
$ ffmpeg -h muxer=ismv
...
-frag_duration     <int>   E.... Maximum fragment duration
-min_frag_duration <int>   E.... Minimum fragment duration
-frag_size         <int>   E.... Maximum fragment size
```

but playing around with these didn't change the output.

How can I create fragments of a specific sice e.g. ~5 seconds each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Audio streams have no keyframes which is what MP4 muxer relies on by default to demarcate fragment boundaries. You will have to set a fragment duration.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a aac -b:a 256k -f mp4 -movflags +empty_moov+separate_moof -frag_duration 10M output.mp4`

#### Note:

1. `faststart` is applicable for regular, non-fragmented output
2. `frag_keyframe` tells ffmpeg to start fragments at *video* keyframes but you don't have a video stream.
3. `-strict experimental` hasn't been required for the native AAC encoder since 2016.
4. `frag_duration` expects a value in microseconds. `10M` = 10 million = 10 seconds.

Comment: Unfortunately the result of this is not playable under Chrome. I managed to get something playable using `faststart+frag_every_frame+empty_moov+separate_moof` but here I am not able to control the `frag_duration`. It seems that the argument gets ignored in this case.

Comment: Works here in Chrome 86 and FF 82. Share full log.

Comment: Are you using MSE SourceBuffer in segment mode?

Comment: I'm just loading a local file in these browsers.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing. If you do that even an MP3 will work on Firefox. But it doesn't if you use this sh*t they call Media Source Extention (MSE) .. I need it in order to partially load audio files instead of downloading the entire file befor playing. And every browser does it's own cr*p to eff things up. Sorry for the rant it's just no fun anymore ..

Comment: You should raise an issue at Chrome on whether this is an inherent limitation of MSE in Chrome.

Comment: It's not a bug though. It's just how the browsers implement it. And I don't even think it's a coincidence that they do it differently than other browsers..

Comment: do you know an option that will ensure that the duration of the track gets stored in the fragmented MP4 as well? Is I use this file reader, it says that the duration is undefined http://download.tsi.telecom-paristech.fr/gpac/mp4box.js/filereader.html

Comment: Which specific field?

Comment: If I look at the File Overview, the duration is 00:00 (or undefined). I'm still not sure how I can seek inside an fMP4. In fact, I am not even sure if it really _has_ to be fragmented in my case. All I want to support is that the user can listen to the audio right away without having to download the entire file. For this to work there should be no need for more fragments than one, right?

Comment: At least technically but then there is MSEs `SourceBuffer` ..