# Mux ts segments to fragmented mp4 in realtime

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, http-live-streaming

I have an HLS stream which plays in the browser. What I want to do is have a URL like `/stream.mp4` that plays the livestream back as a fragmented mp4 from the current point in time. This way you could download the stream as a single file and it would work without any js dependencies.

The method I thought of is:

1. send an mp4 header
2. wait for a new segment
3. convert the segment into an mp4 fragment with `ffmpeg`
4. send the mp4 fragment
5. go to 2.

(I know you can concatenate `.ts` segments but they don't play in Firefox.)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9734251) describes how to create a fragmented mp4 when you have all the segments at hand (tl;dr use `-movflags frag_keyframe+emptymoov`). But I want to do this on the fly so each new HLS segment is converted to an mp4 fragment as soon as it's created.

I think this is similar to what DASH does natively, where any chunk `chunk-$n.m4s` can be appended to `init.m4s` and it'll be a proper fragmented mp4. But can this be done without using DASH?

How can I transmux a ts segment into an mp4 fragment?

Edit: I found a way of doing what I wanted, but not through transmuxing mpegts segments to fmp4. It turns out that later versions of HLS do support fragmented mp4 (like DASH does), and FFmpeg provides the [`-hls_segment_type fmp4`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-6) option for this.