# Problem in playing fragmented MP4 that create with FFMPEG

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavcodec

For creating [fragmented MP4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177797/what-exactly-is-fragmented-mp4fmp4-how-is-it-different-from-normal-mp4) video file, I'm using `FFMPEG AVCodec` library([Accord VideoWriter](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/development/Sources/Extras/Accord.Video.FFMPEG.GPL/VideoFileWriter.cpp)) and set `movflags` with value `frag_keyframe+empty_moov` based on [How to output fragmented mp4 with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616855/how-to-output-fragmented-mp4-with-ffmpeg)

```
 av_dict_set(&videoOptions, "movflags", "frag_keyframe+empty_moov", 0);
 avformat_write_header(oc, &videoOptions);
```

[Sample output video](http://185.153.184.168:8082/videos/1/2021/08/18/12-08-27.mp4)

As you see, video is not played while all of video frames downloaded completely.
I tried to set `moov_size` , `frag_duration` and `min_frag_duration` flags for correction, but doesn't change anything.

Result of all my test:
[image]